# I receive "can't find symbol" errors while calling a constructor from another separate class in command prompt

Tags: java, object, compiler-errors, command-prompt

I am trying to call the class *FileRead* and methods *Display* and *Contents* from another separate class, however it is within the same package. This is my main class. It works within Eclipse. I can type in a text file and it displays it. This class also compiles and runs in command prompt.

```
public class FileRead 
{
    static String theFile;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    static List<String> fileArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    static StringBuffer stringBuff = new StringBuffer();
    
    public FileRead()
    {   
        System.out.println ("Enter your file: ");
        theFile = myScanner.nextLine();
        
        try 
        {
            myScanner = new Scanner(new File(theFile));
            FileReader myFileReader = new FileReader(theFile);
            BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(myFileReader);
            while ((theFile = buffRead.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                fileArray.add(theFile);
            }           
            
            buffRead.close();
        } 
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
    public String Contents()
    {
        for (String str : fileArray) 
        {
            stringBuff.append(str);
            stringBuff.append("\n");
        }
        
        String str = stringBuff.toString();
        return (str);
    }
    
    public void Display()
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Line # " + (i + 1) + " " + fileArray.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //FileRead textFile = new FileRead();
        //textFile.Display();
        //textFile.Contents();
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with this class:

```
public class FileReadShow
{   
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
        try
        {
            FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();
            myTextFile.Contents();
            myTextFile.Display();
        }
        
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this in the command prompt, I get this:

```
javac filereadshow.java
filereadshow.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();
                        ^
  symbol:   class FileRead
  location: class FileReadShow
filereadshow.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class FileRead
  location: class FileReadShow
2 errors
```

I've done some searching around and found the main causes of these errors. I didn't find any typos. I also tried removing one *main* methods from one of these classes but that hadn't worked either. One thing I'm still unsure of is undeclared variables, which is my first question.

1: I am new to constructors, and it looks correct to me, but could the problem be that I have incorrectly called the reference to the object where the *FileRead* constructor is?

2: I have narrowed the errors down to this statement alone `FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();` because no matter what I do with it, this is where the errors are. Could someone please help me determine if the problem is with the *FileRead* script itself, or with the object reference `FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();`?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: FileRead.class is in the current directory as I am able to compile it. I compiled that before trying FileReadShow.

EDIT #2: I switched IDE's and found more information which gave me two compile error descriptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:         -FileRead cannot be resolved to a type         
-FileRead cannot be resolved to a type
```

So far there doesn't seem to be a very definitive answer. I am currently working through fixes that have worked for other people. Such as restarting eclipse/PC, using the "clean" option in the file drop down menu, creating a new class, etc. So far nothing has worked. I will keep trying. Does anyone have any more suggestions I could try?

EDIT #3: Both of my .java files are inside of the package folder that contains everything for Eclipse (.CLASSPATH, .project, src folder, bin folder, etc). Normally when I change directories in command prompt, I go to this package folder and can compile with ease. My exact command prompt input is:

```
C:\Users\D>cd eclipse-workspace\packageone\src\packageone

C:\Users\D\eclipse-workspace\PackageOne\src\PackageOne>javac fileread.java
//As you can see the first one compiled, so I call the second below
C:\Users\D\eclipse-workspace\PackageOne\src\PackageOne>javac filereadshow.java
filereadshow.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();
                        ^
  symbol:   class FileRead
  location: class FileReadShow
filereadshow.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
                        FileRead myTextFile = new FileRead();
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class FileRead
  location: class FileReadShow
2 errors
```

The first .java file (FileRead.java) compiled, the second one (.FileReadShow.java) still results in errors. What am I doing wrong? I've compiled dozens of programs this way and haven't run into this...?

Comment: Is there a file named `FileRead.class` in your current directory? If not, compile `FileRead.java` before you compile `FileReadShow`.

Comment: And please clarify whether there is a `package ...` statement in your two classes.

Comment: I did add they are within the same package, I seem to have forgotten to include that in my copy & paste, but yes the packages are declared and both of these classes are within the same package.

Comment: @user16320675 Let me know if this is correct, I will also add it as an edit to my original question: When I compile my programs using javac in the command prompt, I go to the folder where the .java files are which are under the package name in eclipse-workspace. Normally, these compile with no issues. However, it is just the one program that is having issues. I moved everything to the package folder that contained the .CLASSPATH file. Still the same thing, FileRead.java compiles, FileReadShow.java does not. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have your `.java` files in the correct directory structure, taking your packages into account.

So if you have:

```
package x;

class Foo {}
```

and

```
package x;

class Bar {
        Foo foo;
}
```

They should be at the path `x/Foo.java` and `x/Bar.java` relative to the directory where you run `javac`.

So if you run `javac x/Foo.java` and `javac x/Bar.java`

You'll get:

```
.
└── x
    ├── Bar.class
    ├── Bar.java
    ├── Foo.class
    └── Foo.java
```

When `javac Bar.java` looks for `Foo.class`, it looks for `x/Foo.class`, because `Foo` is in the package `x`. So the directory structure that your files are in must mirror the package structure of your classes.

Comment: I think I understand your answer, and yes they are in the same directory. So my package is called ```PackageOne```. My file path goes like this: ```c\ eclipse-workspace \ PackageOne \ FileRead.java``` For the other class it goes: ```c\ eclipse-workspace \ PackageOne \ FileReadShow.java``` FileRead also has a .class because I was able to compile it, FileReadShow doesn't NOT have a .class because it won't compile.

Comment: Is that what your answer was getting at or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes -- and you need to run `javac PackageOne\FileReadShow.java` in `c:\eclipse-workspace`

Comment: I do change directories if that's what you mean. I change directories in command prompt right into the *PackageOne* folder and then call javac to compile my files.

Comment: You need to run the command `javac PackageOne\FileReadShow.java` *in the `c:\eclipse-workspace` directory* **not** in the `PackageOne` directory.

Comment: I just keep getting the "file not found" error starting from the eclipse-workspace directory and working into the PackageOne directory where the errors change to the symbols not found like the ones I posted?

Comment: What command are you running in `c:\eclipse-workspace`?

Comment: ```javac FileRead.java``` first, which compiles and and I can run it with the java command. ```javac FileReadShow.java``` won't compile. I also tried your suggestion of  ```javac PackageOne\FileReadShow.java``` but it says file not found.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running those commands in `c:\eclipse-workspace` and not in `c:\eclipse-workspace\PackageOne`?

Comment: Yes Sir, absolutely. Your comment of: `Yes -- and you need to run javac PackageOne\FileReadShow.java in c:\eclipse-workspace` made the filepath very clear on what to try, however it's telling me that it is not found. Which is odd.

Comment: That is strange.

Comment: I've discovered new information! I switched from Eclipse to a different IDE and was able to pull this from it: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        FileRead cannot be resolved to a type
        FileRead cannot be resolved to a type``` Looks like I'm doing some more digging into what this means!

Comment: It basically means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Source file names must exactly match class names.
So it should be `FileRead.java` and `FileReadShow.java` and not `fileread.java` and `filereadshow.java` as you have.
Additionally, you sample miss `excerpt` variable declaration.

P.S. In Java it is common to use `camelCase` for variable and method names. So it is better to to change names to `contents()` and `display()`. And we don't insert line break before opening curly brace.

Comment: I have found that in command prompt, capitalization doesn't seem to be a problem. I can compile and run ```fileread.java``` but not ```filereadshow.java```. *FileReadShow* will run in Eclipse, but will not compile or run in Command Prompt. Also I changed the variable declaration, that was a typo while posting it here. Should be all good now.

Comment: The sources you provided are successfully compiled being placed in the same directory.

Comment: I don't understand this because after a conversation with *tgdavies* below, I showed that they are in the same directory (In case you hadn't seen this one): ```So my package is called PackageOne. My file path goes like this: c\ eclipse-workspace \ PackageOne \ FileRead.java For the other class it goes: c\ eclipse-workspace \ PackageOne \ FileReadShow.java FileRead also has a .class because I was able to compile it, FileReadShow doesn't NOT have a .class because it won't compile.```

Comment: Did you get this in your IDE? ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        FileRead cannot be resolved to a type
        FileRead cannot be resolved to a type```

Comment: My Java is a bit rusty but don't you need an import FileRead; statement at the top of the FileReadShow.java file?

Comment: @kiwiron Only if the classes are not in the same package. These two classes are in the same package so there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the answer is. I was able to get both programs to compile in command prompt using:

```
javac packageone\fileread.java packageone\filereadshow.java
```

However, when I tried to run the `FileReadShow` program, it said there was a compilation error, citing the same missing symbols. I just nested the two classes together and called it a day.